# Currency Formatting Issue in Conga Template Conditional Statements

Tags: cpq, conditional, currency, quote-template, conga-composer

I am encountering a problem with currency formatting in a Conga Word template while using conditional statements. The specific code snippet in question is as follows:

```
{ 
    if "«QUOTE_DANI_SURCHARGECOST»" <> "0" 
        "«QUOTE_DANI_SURCHARGECOST »\# Currency" 
        "Not Applicable 
}
```

The objective is to display the value of "«QUOTE_DANI_SURCHARGECOST»" in currency format when it's not equal to zero, and show "Not Applicable" otherwise. However, the currency is not being presented in the expected format.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to correctly format the currency in this context within a Conga template. Your expertise is highly valued, and thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your statement, So what I did below is, the `IF` statement checks if `QUOTE_DANI_SURCHARGECOST` is not zero. If it's not zero, the value is formatted as currency using `\# $#,##0.00, where \#` initiates formatting, `$#` represents the currency symbol, and `##0.00` ensures two decimal places, with zeroes added if needed. If `QUOTE_DANI_SURCHARGECOST` is zero, `"Not Applicable"` is displayed instead

```
    { 
    IF "«QUOTE_DANI_SURCHARGECOST»" <> "0" 
    "«QUOTE_DANI_SURCHARGECOST\# $#,##0.00»" 
    "Not Applicable" 
}
```